# Could you add an option to withdraw a question rather than close it?

Tags: feature-request

The options when choosing to close a question are all rather pejorative and assume the question you wish to close was not asked by you.

Occasionally I find that I ask a question, and then realise (usually after some sleep) that I've been looking at the problem wrongly.  In such cases I'd like to be able to simply withdraw the question rather than close it or flag it.

Would you mind adding a `withdraw your own question` option?

Comment: The close reasons as they stand are not meant to be perjorative. They're maybe frank, since they are by necessity describing something that is not good enough - but if you have better suggested phrasing for any of them, put up a new Meta post. Some close reasons in the past have been removed/changed as a result of suggestions (e.g. "lacks minimal understanding", which caused a few 'ouch' responses).

Comment: No, they shall stand as monuments to your rash decision making to ask others to waste their time helping you solve problems you could have solved yourself with more effort.  Look upon them and weep.

Comment: ^^ what @Will says.  Think first, post later and, by 'later', I mean after 8 hours of debugging and 8 hours of sleep.

Answer (score 15):

> Would you mind adding a withdraw your own question option?

If by "withdraw" you mean "delete", it's not a good idea. It would be prone to abuse.

You can delete your question *if it hasn't received any upvoted answers yet.*

This limitation was instituted because of massive abuse in the past, e.g. users asking questions and then removing them once satisfactory answers have been received - hence breaking the idea of Stack Overflow as a repository of knowledge (and depriving answerers of even their tiny reward in arbitrary points.)

It's unlikely this limitation will ever be lifted.

If by "withdraw" you mean simply adding a new close reason that only the question's owner can trigger - yeah, it would make sense, theoretically, but how often is it needed to justify the new feature? Not often enough.

If a question is answerable, it will be answered; if it isn't, it will be closed and/or deleted.

If you want to let the community know that you realized a question was bad, let them know through a comment and watch it getting closed.

If you are *completely* embarrassed by a question asked by you, you can always request the question to be disassociated from your account.